# Do I need a separate home inspection if I've got a good contractor doing a gut rehab?

Tags: inspection

We're looking at buying a single family home that's... rather out of date. It's basically in gut-rehab shape. We're planning on replacing electrical, plumbing, heating, and even some foundation work. We have a contractor we like and trust. Is there any point in paying a *separate* home inspector?

Comment: Check your local jurisdiction. It's probably unlawful to do work on your house without a permit and approved Inspections

Comment: Not a building inspector. A home inspector, of the kind one normally gets as a contingency when purchasing a house. The contractor would _of course_ get relevant permits and inspections.

Comment: Home inspectors have NO authority.

Answer (score 2):

You still might want the inspection.  Even though you don't care about the electrical, plumbing, heating, wall and floor finish, you are counting on the underlying structure to be sound.  You might want to know about, for example, evidence of water damage / possible mold, rot in the sill or beams, sagging floors, possible asbestos, evidence of termites or other pests - many things you might not have thought of.

You may be able to ask the inspector to place less emphasis on the systems you know you plan to replace.

Comment: Oh, there are _definitely_ sagging floors and asbestos tile. It's to that level already :)

Answer (score 0):

I have purchased homes without an inspection report, your lender may require one, but if doing everything for your personal residence his contract with the scope of work may even make the lender happy.